# Converting Multiple Excel Files Into One

Tags: python, export-to-csv

I have multiple excel files saved in a folder which I converted into one Data Frame. I wrote a python code to combine all the csv files into one Data Frame. The issue is that the column format is not what I expect to be. This means that the original files contained separate Open, High, Low, Close and Volume functions but the combined Data Frame contains all these data merged into one. I want to merge the files such that the original column format is preserved that is Open, High, Low, Close, Volume are separate columns.

Here is my code:

`import os
import pandas as pd
os.chdir("C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/Zerodha/Day2/")
path = "C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/Zerodha/Day2/"
files =os.listdir(path)
values =pd.DataFrame()
for f in files:
    data = pd.read_csv(f, delim_whitespace=True)
    values = values.append(data)`

This is the output of my master data Frame:

[Values Data Frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtpzV.png)

However, I would like the master Data Frame to have Seperate Columns as shown:

[Original Files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWTwr.png)

Any feedbacks will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Provide a plain-text snippet of one of the CSV files in question. Excel hides the column delimiter, so a screenshot of the CSV data - as understood by Excel - does not help in this case.

Comment: Excel and CSV files have nothing in common. A CSV is just a flat text file using commas as delimiters. An Excel file is a ZIP package containing XML files with a specific schema. You could combine CSV files just like any other text file by concatenating them, as long as they don't have headers. Obviously, you can't do that with a ZIP package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a column separator that matches the contents of the CSV files. For example use `pd.read_csv(f, delimiter=',')` if the plain-text content of the CSV files is similar to below:

```
date,open,high,low,close,volume
2020-11-09 09:15:00+05:30,10.25,10.45,10.25,10.45,300
```

Reason is that `pandas.read_csv(fileobj, delim_whitespace=True)` expects whitespaces as column separators. If the CSV files have the format assumed in my example (comma-separated), then having `delim_whitespace=True` will result in the problem encountered.

A snippet from [pandas.read_csv() docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) on `delim_whitespace`:

> **delim_whitespace: bool, default False**
>
> Specifies whether or not whitespace (e.g. ' ' or '    ') will be used as the sep. Equivalent to setting sep='\s+'. If this option is set to True, nothing should be passed in for the delimiter parameter.

Comment: Just for the Extra Info will the application run faster if the files are imported into the db and then are read from the Database.